# QGIS 2.4 Print Composer Will Not Export Image

Tags: qgis, print-composer, mac, qgis-2.4

I am running QGIS 2.4 on a Macbook Pro (Mavericks) and am having problems with the print composer.

Recently, my composer window goes totally white when trying to export images or pdfs and nothing else happens.

Yesterday, I was able to export images, but today nothing.

I am still learning QGIS and am not sure if this is something I did or an issue with the print composer.

Comment: Print Composer normally works well but maybe you are at the limits of your hardware (RAM).  Can you edit your question to include the page size and resolution of the image you are trying to export plus the amount of memory you have?

Comment: It's normal for the window to go white while the Composer generates output. Is your map big (many features)? What layer types do you have loaded?

Comment: @underdark having the same problem over here. I have a OSM as a basemap. Could that be a problem?

Comment: @Stophface please open a new thread and include detail such as if you are using OSM vector data. In case you use the Openlayers plugin, please note that it does not support printing and this question has been asked multiple times already.

Comment: @underdark all good. That is not worth opening a new topic. I was using an Openlayers PlugIn. Luckily, there are many sites where you can download OSM data and work with them.